# Error de importación de modulos al crear ejecutable con pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Hice un proyecto en **python 3.7** usando **pyqt5** y varios paquetes como *matplotlib, rasterio, geopandas, etc*. debo empaquetar el proyecto un ejecutable para *windows* y *linux* y estoy usando **pyinstaller** para hacer esta labor. esta es la estructura del proyecto

```
run.py
USLE
|   home.py
|   inicio.py
|   __init__.py
|
+---controllers
|       a_controller.py
|       c_controller.py
|       k_controller.py
|       ls_controller.py
|       p_controller.py
|       r_controller.py
|       s_controller.py
|       __init__.py
|
+---gui
|       home_ui.py
|       icons_rc.py
|       inicio_ui.py
|       __init__.py
|
\---models
        a_tab.py
        c_tab.py
        k_tab.py
        r_tab.py
        start_tab.py
        __init__.py
```

Al inicio tenia un problema para empaquetar *rasterio* puesto que *pyinstaller* no reconocía el paquete al momento de realizar el análisis del archivo **run.py** que es el archivo de entrada del proyecto, usando y adaptando la respuesta a este problema https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53149750/something-wrong-with-how-im-bundling-rasterio-into-an-executable pude solucionar lo de empaquetar *rasterio*, sin embargo, al momento de ejecutar el **.exe** que me genera *pyinstaller* ahora me arroja este error:

> ````
> File "usle\models\k_tab.py", line 2, in <module>
>       File "C:\Users\david\Anaconda3\envs\car-usle\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
>         exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
>       File "site-packages\geopandas\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
>       File "C:\Users\david\Anaconda3\envs\car-usle\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
>         exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
>       File "site-packages\geopandas\geoseries.py", line 11, in <module>
>       File "C:\Users\david\Anaconda3\envs\car-usle\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
>         exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
>       File "site-packages\pyproj\__init__.py", line 70, in <module>
>       File "pyproj/_datadir.pyx", line 6, in init pyproj._datadir
>     ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyproj.datadir'
>     [9368] Failed to execute script run```
> ````

---

Éste es el archivo **run.spec** que estoy usando:

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None
block_cipher = None
import glob, os
rasterio_imports_paths = glob.glob(r'C:\Users\david\Anaconda3\envs\car-usle\Lib\site-packages\rasterio\*.py')
rasterio_imports = ['rasterio._shim']


for item in rasterio_imports_paths:
    current_module_filename = os.path.split(item)[-1]
    current_module_filename = 'rasterio.'+current_module_filename.replace('.py', '')
    rasterio_imports.append(current_module_filename)

a = Analysis(['run.py'],
             pathex=['D:\\CAR-USLE\\car-usle'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=rasterio_imports,
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='car-usle',
          debug=True,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               name='car-usle')
```

No se como solucionar este problema. ¿Alguno tiene alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Aunque tu proyecto use PyQt5 no implica que el problema tenga que ver con esa librería, lo que señala el error es que no empaqueta correctamente la librería [pyproj](https://pypi.org/project/pyproj/). Si deseas ayuda provee un [mre] donde debes mostrar el .spec

Comment: gracias por la sugerencia, añadí el .spec

Comment: revisa https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55824830/i-get-error-no-module-named-pyproj-datadir-after-i-made-py-to-exe-with-py